# Is bin-packing possible in this special case?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, packing-problem

Choose 5 primes arbitrarily: p1, p2, p3, p4, p5

Make five bins of size:

n1*p2*p3*p4*p5

n2*p1*p3*p4*p5

n3*p1*p2*p4*p5

n4*p1*p2*p3*p5

n5*p1*p2*p3*p4

where n1 < p1, n2 < p2, n3 < p3, etc...

We then make an arbitrary multiset consisting of one's, our five arbitrary primes, their pairwise products, and their three-way products (we don't have to have at least one of each element, and duplicates of elements are allowed).

If the total size of the elements in the multiset is less than (or equal to?) the total size of the five bins, is there always a way to pack these objects into the bins without overflowing?

What if we were to choose n primes, make n bins, and take numbers that are up to the product of (n-2) primes?

Comment: If i understood the question correctly then $\{2,2,2,2,17\}$ for $p_i$ and $\{1,1,1,1,5\}$ for $n_i$ is a valid counter-example ?, please reply so i can post an answer

Comment: @Ahmad What would your counter example be (what are the elements in the multiset)?

Comment: I don't think quotation marks  mean what you think they do.

Comment: @WeiHu as he explain in the question, they are $p_1,p_2,...,p_5,p_1 p_2 , ... , p_4 p_5 , p_1 p_2 p_3,.... ,p_3 p_4 p_5$.

Comment: Does the arbitrary multiset also contain p1*p1, .... p5*p5 and p1*p1*p1 , p1*p1*p2 ..... p4*p5*p5, p5*p5*p5 ?

Comment: @BrianTrial no, it would not

Comment: @Ahmad, your proposal is NOT a counter-example, if I calculated correctly.  Your selections for n are too small and violate the condition "total size of the elements in the multiset is less than (or equal to?) the total size of the five bins".  Thus, it is not a counter-example.
Your bin sizes are: 8x17,8x17,8x17,8x17,16x5 (total size 624) In which you want to pack 2,2,2,2,17 ; 2x2 (6 times) , 2x17 (4 times) ; 2x2x17 ( 6 times) , 2x2x2 ( 4 times )  (total size 625, and 625 > 624 ).